# "unresolved identifier" came out unexpected

Tags: swift

I am new with Swift and don't understand everything now.
What I am trying to do is create a variable which is not equal to `leegRectY`. `leegRectY` has a `yGrid[]` in it. So I create the variable `randomm` and keep doing that until it is not equal to `leegRectY`. But when I want to return `randomm` Xcode says that it has not been identified yet. But I have already identified `randomm`

I know I am doing something wrong, so please be kind ;-)

Thanks

```
func getRectY() -> CGFloat {
    let yGrid:Array = [(CGRectGetMaxY(frame)/4 * 0),
        (CGRectGetMaxY(frame)/4 * 1),
        (CGRectGetMaxY(frame)/4 * 2),
        (CGRectGetMaxY(frame)/4 * 3)]

    for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        var randomm = yGrid[Int.random(0...3)]
        if leegRectY != randomm { break }
    }
    return CGFloat(randomm)  // XCODE: Use of unresolved identifier 'randomm'
}
```

**EDIT:**

The variable is only defined in this function, or in this case only in the for loop. So when I put `var randomm = 0` before my loop the value doesn't change from nil. Maybe this is useful information for you...

Comment: Look where `randomm` is defined – do you know what the "scope" of a variable is?

Comment: `randomm` is only in this function defined

Comment: No, only in the for loop (Swift is not JavaScript).

Comment: what would be an other solution?

Comment: I tried to define `randomm` in my class but the value didn't change anymore by the for loop

Comment: You should declare it outside of the `for` loop (probably on the line right before the `for` loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "body" of the for-statement is a "code block"

```
{ statements... }
```

and in Swift (and many other programming languages)
variables are only "valid" inside the code block in which they
are declared. More precisely, the *scope* of a variable ranges from its declaration until the
end of the closest enclosing code block in which it is declared.

In your case, `var randomm` is declared in the code-block of the
for-statement and it is not known outside of that block.

You have to declare the variable at the scope of your function instead:

```
func getRectY() -> CGFloat {
    // ...

    var randomm = CGFloat(0.0)
    for (var i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        randomm = yGrid[Int.random(0...3)] // <-- no "var" here !!!
        if leegRectY != randomm { break }
    }
    return randomm
}
```

or perhaps slightly simpler:

```
func getRectY() -> CGFloat {
    // ...

    var randomm : CGFloat
    do {
        randomm = yGrid[Int.random(0...3)]
    } while leegRectY == randomm
    return randomm
}
```

Comment: without that var it worked :-)  Only your second solution is not working for me. Thanks Martin R!